# Is there a way to use SNI (Server Name Indicator) in 4.0.x mongodb-java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, mongodb-java

Until mongodb-java-driver 3.12.3, it is possible to use [MongoClientOptions.Builder#socketFactory](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html#socketFactory(javax.net.SocketFactory)) (deprecated) method to inject pre-made SocketFactory object to be able to use SNI to connect with SSL/TLS.

In the new driver (4.x), that has been removed (adviced to use SSLContext instead) and it is not clear how to use SNI with SSL/TLS connection. It is possible to use [MongoClientSettings.Builder#applyToSslSettings(Block block)](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.Builder.html#applyToSslSettings(com.mongodb.Block)) to create necessary SSLContext and invalid hostname allowance. However, as it is mentioned, it is not obvious how to set SNI to connect.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you *need* to do anything? Ruby driver for example handles sni automatically.

Comment: I see, well according to their JIRA (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2801?jql=project%20%3D%20JAVA%20AND%20text%20~%20sni) the doc is missing. Maybe as you said it is handled automatically. However, I cannot find anything supports that.

Comment: Atlas free tier requires sni, and all drivers must test themselves against atlas free tier. So generally I'd expect that official MongoDB drivers support sni transparently. Is there a problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: See e.g.: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#tls

Comment: The source contains several references to enabling sni as well. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver

Comment: I believe the driver supports, that's why I'm trying to find it. I haven't got any concrete problem yet because, I was reading and experimenting other SSL config. I would expect to be able to set SNI somehow because it used to be possible.

Comment: In that case I suggest trying to connect to `openssl s_server`, you should see whether sni is sent there I imagine.

Comment: I checked the repository and most of the SNI code yields in internal package, which may also indicate automatic handling. I will give a try with a server setup. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It seems it is possible to connect to Atlas without using SNI specification through java driver. Thanks again @Oleg.